# Disregard old CoreData Model and use new updated model for users who are updating to new version of app?

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

My app gets less than 5 downloads per month. I don't think it has any active users. In this case, how do I just use the latest changes of the CoreData model without migrating. The model is for AppSettings, and always just a singe record, which will get many changes in app updates. Rather than migrating, how could my app just replace old settings model with the newest and just use reset default values.

I have another model, for more important user data, this model will get updated normally with migration, but the AppSettings Coredata entity model should get replaced and reset with latest if the update contains changes to the entity?

Comment: Why use Core Data for a single record of app settings? This is what `UserDefaults` is for.

Comment: I used to use userDefaults by jsonserializing the settings object. Several SO answers suggest not to save objects in userDefaults. But I like to persist AppSettings object as a whole rather than individual properties in UserDefaults. This avoid the read/write costs of UserDefaults and find it's easier to manage with scale.
One suggest I found is separate Persistent Store Containers, so the one AppSettings belongs to could be trashed and recreated. Have you ever experienced with that?

Comment: If you only have a single record, what read/write costs are you concerned about?

Comment: @LarvusKoji UserDefaults is an in-memory dictionary that occasionally gets persisted to a file. Certainly the read/write costs can't be worse than using Core Data which has way more overhead involved.